# Grails JUnit Test case, doesn't execute method marked with @BeforeClass annotation

Tags: java, grails, junit

Here's my code below, testSample() gets executed successfully. Please suggest what could possibly be wrong

```
class DataServiceTest extends GrailsUnitTestCase{
    @BeforeClass
    static void onceExecutedBeforeAll() {
        println(" Print before Start Test Cases");
    }
    @Test
    public void testSample(){
        println(" Inside Sample");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend a TestCase and use annotations at the same time. If you want to create a test suite with annotations, you can use `@RunWith` annotation:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ DataServiceTest.class, OtherTest.class })
public class AllTests {
// empty
}


public class DataServiceTest {  // no extends here
@BeforeClass
static void onceExecutedBeforeAll() {
    println(" Print before Start Test Cases");
}
@Test
public void testSample(){
    println(" Inside Sample");
}
}
```

Another option using JUnit could be annotating the method with `@Before` and removing `extends GrailsUnitTestCase` from the class.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran you are welcome! Do you mind removing the upvote on my answer? I'm trying to get the Unsung Hero badge... Thank you!

Comment: So modest of you, I tried but Stackoverflow isn't allowing now